# How does trap / kill work in bash on Linux?

Tags: bash

My sample file

traptest.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo trapped' TERM
while :
do
  sleep 1000
done
```

$ traptest.sh &

> > [1] 4280

$ kill %1      <-- kill by job number works

> > Terminated
> >
> > trapped

$ traptest.sh &

> > [1] 4280

$ kill 4280     <-- kill by process id doesn't work?

> > (sound of crickets, process isn't killed)

If I remove the trap statement completely, kill process-id works again?

Running some RHEL 2.6.18-194.11.4.el5 at work.  I am really confused by this behaviour, is it right?

Comment: This is super weird. I'm trying to investigate but i can't find anything logical with this. +1 for this question

Comment: Yes, but sleep starts it's own process, that's the one you need to kill. One thing that's weird is that kill %1 kills it immediattely, but kill <number> needs you to first fg before it is killed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
kill [pid]
```

send the TERM signal exclusively to the specified PID.

```
kill %1
```

send the TERM signal to the job #1's entire process group, in this case to the script pid + his children (sleep).

I've verified that with strace on sleep process and on script process

Anyway, someone got a similar problem here (but with SIGINT instead of SIGTERM): http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=34.

Quoting the most important sentence:

**kill -INT %1 sends the signal to the job’s process group, not the backgrounded pid!**

Comment: So it uses kill in a polling manner? How much polling is enough? lol

Answer (score 8):

This is expected behavior. Default signal sent by `kill` is `SIGTERM`, which you are catching by your trap. Consider this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# traptest.sh

trap "echo Booh!" SIGINT SIGTERM
echo "pid is $$"

while :                 # This is the same as "while true".
do
    a=1
done
```

(sleep really creates a new process and the behavior is clearer with my example I guess).

So if you run `traptest.sh` in one terminal and `kill TRAPTEST_PROCESS_ID` from another terminal, output in the terminal running traptest will be `Booh!` as expected (and the process will **NOT** be killed). If you try sending `kill -s HUP TRAPTEST_PROCESS_ID`, it will kill the traptest process.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/275433/what-does-1-in-kill-1-mean) should clear up the `%1` confusion.

Note: the code example is taken from [tldp](http://tldp.org)

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question - the while is clearer.  I thought kill was doing a SIGTERM, but it seems adding SIGINT to the trap allows for kill process-id to be handled.

Comment: I beleive not so. Whether you catching SIGINT or not does have no effect on how SIGTERM is handled. Have you tried the scenario I described in my answer? I mean killing the process with different signals to see what is happening?

Comment: Working with Davide's answer concurrently - if I just trap SIGTERM, and put a "sleep 10s" in the place of the while loop, the script does handle the trap - but only after the sleep exits.  Bash doesn't handle the signal until the child process returns.  If I just have the while loop, it's handled immediately.  Your answer was constructive in helping me understand the issue by experimenting with removing the child sleep process. Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

Davide Berra explained the difference between `kill %<jobspec>` and `kill <PID>`, but not *how* that difference results in what you observed. After all, Unix signal handlers should be called pretty much instantaneously, so why does sending a `SIGTERM` to the script alone not trigger its trap handler?

The `bash` man page explains why, in [the last paragraph of the **SIGNALS** section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Signals):

> If `bash` is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for
>   which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the
>   command completes.

So, the signal **was** delivered immediately, but the handler execution *was deferred until `sleep` exited*.

Hence, with `kill %<jobspec>`:

- Both the script and `sleep` received `SIGTERM`
- `bash` registered the signal, noticed that a `trap` was set for it, and queued the handler for future execution
- `sleep` exited immediately
- `bash` noted `sleep`'s exit, and ran the trap handler

whereas with `kill <script_PID>`:

- Only the script received `SIGTERM`
- `bash` registered the signal, noticed that a `trap` was set for it, and queued the handler for future execution
- `sleep` exited *after 1000 seconds*
- `bash` noted `sleep`'s exit, and ran the trap handler

Obviously, you didn't want long enough to see that last bit. :)

---

If you're interested in the gory details, [download the `bash` source code](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) and look in `trap.c`, specifically the `trap_handler()` and `run_pending_traps()` functions.